# Javascript Replace removes HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Javascript's string replace function seems to be stripping HTML tags, is there a way to disable this?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDd7w/

```
$('#pageEnumeration').text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace(/^Showing \d+-\d+ of/, 'Showing ');
});
```

```
<p id="pageEnumeration">
  Showing 1-25 of 45 records found:
  <br>
  containing the terms:
  <span class="italic">cat</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what it comes down to is the fact that you're accessing the text node through .text(), which does completely strip out markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/dkLLX/

Is this what you were looking for?

```
$('#pageEnumeration').html(function(i, htm){
    return htm.replace(/^Showing \d+-\d+ of/, 'Showing ');
});
```

You need to access using the .html() method, not .text() if you want to preserve element nodes.

Comment: Why serialize, replace, destroy, parse and rebuild the entire content when you could just replace the targeted text?

Comment: This will work perfectly. This code will only run once per page view in a very specific context, so I am not worried about wasted performance potential.

Comment: @mori57: No, what I'm saying is that using `.html()` in this manner is an anti-pattern. It's far too destructive. Not a big deal in this small case, but people see stuff like this, and then use it on a regular basis.

Comment: ...also, you're actually serializing the DOM twice. Your inner `$(this).html()` call isn't needed since the DOM has already been serialized and passed to the callback as an argument.

Comment: Instead of `$(this)` use the second argument to the callback. `...html(function(i, htm) { return htm.replace(...`

Comment: Hey, I hadn't even thought of that! Thanks! It's nice to learn something while trying to help someone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the specific text node, or process `innerHTML` directly. The stripping of tags is caused by `text()`.

```
var $pageEnum = $('#pageEnumeration');

if ($pageEnum.length > 0) {
    $pageEnum[0].innerHTML = $pageEnum[0].innerHTML.replace(/^Showing \d+-\d+ of/, 'Showing ');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TDd7w/2/)

Comment: .html() is the jQuery specific call for .innerHTML, right? So, the same thing could be done `$pageEnum[0].html($pageEnum[0].html().replace(/^Showing \d+-\d+ of/, 'Showing ');` correct?

Comment: @mori57: You are right. I don't use jQuery that much, so I end up with a mix of DOM and jQuery.

Comment: Heh. No worries. It's good to remember under all this jQuery jazz how Javascript works! :)