# How can I use ".replace()" and ".html()" to turn plaintext into an image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I am attempting to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944985/6111540) in order to take classic BCCode `[img]{url}[/img]` and display an html image from it. As seen in my code snippet, I have been able to successfully do something similar with `[b]text[/b]`. For some reason, though, with `[img][/img]` the image doesn't display at all.

So, **how can I use `.replace()` and `.html()` to turn plaintext into an image tag?**

```js
$('#boldText').click(function() {
  $('#bold').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[b\]/g, '<b>');
  }); // Replace opening tag
  $('#bold').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</b>');
  }); // Replace closing tag
});
$('#createImage').click(function() {
  $('#image').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[img\]/g, '<img src="');
  }); // Replace opening tag
  $('#image').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[\/img\]/g, '">');
  }); // Replace closing tag
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="bold">
  [b]bold text[/b]
</p>
<button id="boldText">
  Make above text bold
</button>
<p id="image">
  [img]http://i.imgur.com/mFJlvPf.jpg[/img]
</p>
<button id="createImage">
  Make above text into image
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem of your code is in replacing string to tag in two part. When javascript  trying to insert `<img src="` or `">` into html, browser doesn't insert it because it is invalid tag. Use both of `.replace()` after string for chain in one `.html()` function.

```js
$('#boldText').click(function() {
  $('#bold').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[b\]/g, '<b>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</b>');
  }); 
});
$('#createImage').click(function() {
  $('#image').html(function(i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/\[img\]/g, '<img src="').replace(/\[\/img\]/g, '">');
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="bold">
  [b]bold text[/b]
</p>
<button id="boldText">
  Make above text bold
</button>
<p id="image">
  [img]http://i.imgur.com/mFJlvPf.jpg[/img]
</p>
<button id="createImage">
  Make above text into image
</button>
```